# ExtensionManager null in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix, envdte

In previous versions of Visual Studio I could use the following code to retrieve information about a certain installed extension (vsix):

```
IVsExtensionManager manager = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsExtensionManager)) as IVsExtensionManager;
if (manager != null)
{
    VsExtension extension = new VsExtension();
    IInstalledExtension info = manager.GetInstalledExtension(cExtensionProductId);
}
```

In the new Visual Studio 2017 version, the '`manager`' variable is always null. Microsoft changed the way to retrieve the information (they no longer use the system registry), but I can't find another way to retrieve the info.

Do you know where I can find more information and/or provide a sample of the new implementation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that for VS 2017 you are using VS 2017 specific references to the extension manager. It should be **Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll** and
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll**.

For a working example see https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#ExtensionsList.

Comment: Using the code of the example results in a  "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IVsExtensionManager'.'
"

Comment: Adding both dlls, ExtensionManager.dll and ExtensionEngine.dll, results in the following error: CS0433 The type 'IInstalledExtension' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager should be Version=15.0.0.0 as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I finally found the location of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll v.15.0.0.0.

Comment: Location of Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\

Comment: How did you know developers need to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll?

Comment: @Odrai I'm unfortunately can't currently recall how I discovered Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll.

Comment: My Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll was in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Answer (score 0):

Is the ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsExtensionManager)) returns null ? or "as IVsExtensionManager" becomes null ?

Comment: The 'as IVsExtensionManager' returns null.